# enctype does not work along with the id in beginform through a modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Good night people.

I am developing a system that saves the information of the employees along with the path of the image to make display in another page, until then without problem.

I decided to open the Create view in ModalPopup through the view index to avoid too many uploads, except that it saves all information except the image path. I made a debugging and realized that the id I put in the beginform overrides the enctype, I use the id to give the create button in the modal. Can someone give me a hand. below is the code and some images.
**CONTROLLER PESSOA**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Nivel = new SelectList(db.Nivels, "NivelId", "Nome");
        ViewBag.Gabinetes = new SelectList(db.Gabinetes, "GabineteId", "Nome");
        return PartialView();
    }

    // POST: Pessoas/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create(PessoaView view)
    {

     try
     {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Pessoas.Add(view.Pessoa);

            if (view.Foto != null)
            {
                var pic = Utilidades.UploadPhto(view.Foto);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pic))
                {
                    view.Pessoa.Photo = string.Format("~/Content/Fotos/{0}", pic);
                }
            }


            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { resultado = true, mensagem = "Cadastro com Sucesso!" });
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<ModelError> erros = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(item => item.Errors);

            return Json(new { resultado = false, mensagem = erros });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
    }
        return Json(view);
    }
```

**VIEW CREATE**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Pessoas",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype = "multipart/form-data",@id = "formCrud"})))
```

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<hr />

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Foto, new { type = "file" })
        <br />
    </div>
  ..........
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btnAcao = $("input[type='button']");
    var formulario = $("#formCrud");

    btnAcao.on("click", submeter);

    function submeter() {

        if (formulario.valid()) {

            var url = formulario.prop("action");
            var metodo = formulario.prop("method");

            var dadosformulario = formulario.serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:metodo,
                data:dadosformulario,
                success: tratarRetorno,
            });
        }

        function tratarRetorno(resultadoServidor) {

            if (resultadoServidor.resultado) {

                toastr['success'](resultadoServidor.mensagem);

                $("#minhaModal").modal('hide');

            }
            else {

                toastr['error'](resultadoServidor.mensagem);
            }

        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Adding an `id` attribute does not _override the enctype attribute_. You cannot send a file input using ajax like that. You need to send a `FormData` object ad set the correct ajax options - refer [How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681). Why do you have `Html.BeginForm` inside another `Html.BeginForm`?